# Crystal Report Load Report Failed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, crystal-reports, shared-hosting

Simple ASP.NET application to test if crystal report installed on shared server is working or not.
I am still getting Load Report Failed error.
ad report failed. at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened() at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob) at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename)

Version : 13.2000.0
OS : Win Server 20112 64bit

Tested : Temp file access. Temp report files re getting created in the temp folder.
But still getting "Load Report Failed"